# Kubernetes ERROR 502 when expose Nexus3 with Nginx Ingress Controller and LetsEncrypt

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, lets-encrypt, nexus3

i'm trying to expose Nexus 3 using an Nginx controller with letEncrypt, but I get 502 Bad Gateway.
I created this files:

**Namespace: **

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: nexus
spec: {}
status: {}
```

**Persistent Volume: **

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nexus-pv
  namespace: nexus
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 20Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/sonatype-work"
```

**Persistent volume claim: **

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: nexus-pvc
  namespace: nexus
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Gi
```

**Deployment: **

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: nexus
  name: nexus
  namespace: nexus
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nexus
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: nexus
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: volume-mount-hack
        image: busybox
        command: ["sh", "-c", "chown -R 200:200 /nexus-data"]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: nexus-pv
          mountPath: /nexus-data
      containers:
      - image: sonatype/nexus3:3.56.0
        name: nexus3
        resources: {}
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8081
        - containerPort: 5000
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /nexus-data
            name: nexus-pv
      volumes:
        - name: nexus-pv
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: nexus-pvc
status: {}
```

**Service: **

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: nexus
  name: nexus-svc
  namespace: nexus
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8081
    targetPort: 8081
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  - port: 5000
    targetPort: 5000
    protocol: TCP
    name: docker
  selector:
    app: nexus
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

**Ingress: **

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nexus-ingress
  namespace: nexus
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
    ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 1G
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  # CHANGE ME
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /nexus
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service: 
            name: nexus-svc
            port:
              number: 8081
  # CHANGE ME
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /docker
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: nexus-svc
            port:
              number: 5000
```

In the namespace ** Ingress ** i have these resources:

```
NAME                                                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE
pod/cert-manager-66f74b6b4d-sk8fr                             1/1     Running   2 (24h ago)   7d23h
pod/cert-manager-cainjector-5b7db87fff-jmkct                  1/1     Running   5 (24h ago)   7d23h
pod/cert-manager-webhook-77b8ffb7dd-gpwrx                     1/1     Running   0             7d23h
pod/nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller-7d86bb8bb7-djfsl   1/1     Running   0             7d23h
pod/nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller-7d86bb8bb7-rtx5d   1/1     Running   0             7d23h

NAME                                                       TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)                      AGE
service/cert-manager                                       ClusterIP      10.102.140.107   <none>           9402/TCP                     7d23h
service/cert-manager-webhook                               ClusterIP      10.100.77.169    <none>           443/TCP                      7d23h
service/nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.107.124.46    XXX.XXX.XX.XXX   80:31898/TCP,443:32230/TCP   7d23h
service/nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.97.177.108    <none>           443/TCP                      7d23h

NAME                                                     READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/cert-manager                             1/1     1            1           7d23h
deployment.apps/cert-manager-cainjector                  1/1     1            1           7d23h
deployment.apps/cert-manager-webhook                     1/1     1            1           7d23h
deployment.apps/nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller   2/2     2            2           7d23h

NAME                                                                DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/cert-manager-66f74b6b4d                             1         1         1       7d23h
replicaset.apps/cert-manager-cainjector-5b7db87fff                  1         1         1       7d23h
replicaset.apps/cert-manager-webhook-77b8ffb7dd                     1         1         1       7d23h
replicaset.apps/nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller-7d86bb8bb7   2         2         2       7d23h
```

The ** ClusterIssuer ** is in the default namespace:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
  kind: ClusterIssuer
  metadata:
    annotations:
      kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
        {"apiVersion":"cert-manager.io/v1","kind":"ClusterIssuer","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"letsencrypt"},"spec":{"acme":{"email":"mymail@outlook.com","privateKeySecretRef":{"name":"letsencrypt"},"server":"https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory","solvers":[{"http01":{"ingress":{"class":"nginx","podTemplate":{"spec":{"nodeSelector":{"kubernetes.io/os":"linux"}}}}}}]}}}
    creationTimestamp: "2023-06-24T14:29:51Z"
    generation: 1
    name: letsencrypt
    resourceVersion: "6309"
    uid: 79f2c627-c5eb-4ee1-9a6c-2b07ddc4c6f2
  spec:
    acme:
      email: mymail@outlook.com
      preferredChain: ""
      privateKeySecretRef:
        name: letsencrypt
      server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
      solvers:
      - http01:
          ingress:
            class: nginx
            podTemplate:
              metadata: {}
              spec:
                nodeSelector:
                  kubernetes.io/os: linux
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""
```

Can someone help me to understand what is wrong in my configuration ?
Thank you so much

When i see the nginx-controller logs, I found this error:

```html
I0702 13:49:23.761490       7 event.go:285] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress", Name:"nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller-7d86bb8bb7-rtx5d", UID:"6c7cb076-911b-41df-984c-ba6658523022", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"5825", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
2023/07/02 13:49:30 [error] 3154#3154: *5647494 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 10.244.0.0, server: _, request: "GET /nexus HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://10.244.1.112:8081/", host: "XXX.XXX.XX.XXX"
```

I tryed to expose Nexus3 with NodePort and is working. But for me is impossible to expose it with Nginx Ingress